# Export barcode in excel sheet (in Laravel)

Tags: php, excel, laravel, barcode

I implemented this library to generate barcodes images in my laravel project https://github.com/milon/barcode

For generating the excel sheet i use this library :
https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

For the barcode image i just add a value in my database and then i convert that value in a barcode image and know i need to export the barcode in excel

For exporting the barcode i tried many things but none of them seems to work 
in my view i tried different methods for exporting the barcode

The first method :

```
 <td><img src="data:storage/app/upload/;base64,{!! DNS1D::getBarcodePNG("$employee->barcode", 'C39')!!}" ></td>
```

and gives me the following error:

> (1/1) PHPExcel_Exception File
>   data:storage/app/upload/;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAcAAAAAeAQMAAACBqFzbAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN
>   AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAACpJREFUOI1jOHD
>   /Jk/B878OcN//gyxGKSHYVTjqMZRjaMaRzWOaqSXRgC0qVOpA6XqWgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
>   not found!

when i use this code :

```
<td>{!!  DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML("$employee->barcode", "C39")!!}</td>
```

it gives me the following error:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> The webpage at
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/employees/J80302041D/more/excel might be
>   temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web
>   address. ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

the controller that i use to export the barcode:

```
public function excel($nr_personal,Request $request)
    {
        $employees = Employee::where('nr_personal',$nr_personal)->get();
        $worker = Employee::where('nr_personal',$nr_personal)->first();

        Excel::create('Employee Excel', function($excel) use ($employees, $worker) {
            $excel->sheet('Excel sheet', function($sheet) use ( $employees, $worker) {
                $sheet->loadView('admin.employees.excel')->with('employees', $employees)
                                                            ->with('worker', $worker);
                $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');

            });

})->export('xls');

}
```

How can i export the barcode in a excel sheet??

Comment: Do you have a folder called `storage/app/upload`?  Do you have an *internal* website at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/employees/J80302041D/more/excel`?  (Paste that into your browser to see if it's working properly.)

Comment: yes i have folder called that,but i didn't understand whats a internal website

Comment: Actually that `storage/app/upload` is in the wrong place.  Looks like the PHP is trying to generate a Base64 string containing a PNG image of the barcode. The beginning should be something like `data:image/png;base64,` and you can test the string at sites like [this](https://www.base64decode.net/base64-image-decoder) ... although I'm having trouble getting an image out of the string you posted.  Unless the library has an alternate format it in which to produce the image, then you'll have to figure out how to decode a Base64 image in Excel.

Comment: and forget what I said about "internal website".  127.0.0.1 is a loopback address:  **[https://www.lifewire.com/network-computer-special-ip-address-818385](read more here.)**  I think you need to go back to the documentation for this library because you have a few problems going on.  Or, try to find a barcode font.  Good Luck!

Comment: I tried it with data:image/png;base64, but it gave me same result as above:
,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAcAAAAAeAQMAAACBqFzbAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAACpJREFUOI1jOHD /Jk/B878OcN//gyxGKSHYVTjqMZRjaMaRzWOaqSXRgC0qVOpA6XqWgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== not found!



it migh be the fault of the libary that generates the excel and saw the documentation but i didnt see anything regarding this problem

Comment: ok i understand thanks for the help